# how to decrypt data on golang from webcrypte encrypt

Tags: go, encryption, webcrypto-api

- it want to encrypt data on web and decrypt on golang server
- when iv size is 12, it run well
- fail when size is 16
- the js library is using 16 iv size
- the golang decrypt code is

```
h := sha256.New()
io.WriteString(h, "123")
key := h.Sum(nil)

c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

out, err := gcm.Open(nil, encrypted[0:gcm.NonceSize()], encrypted[gcm.NonceSize():], nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

- the javascript encryte code

```js
const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12)); 
const alg = { name: 'AES-GCM', iv: iv }; 
const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', pwHash, alg, false, ['encrypt']);
const ptUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(plaintext); 
const ctBuffer = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(alg, key, ptUint8);
```

- using 16 bit size
- ok for using NewGCMWithNonceSize()
- think

Comment: [`NewGCM()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#NewGCM) requires a 12 bytes nonce (12 bytes is the recommended nonce size for GCM). For other nonce sizes (as far as allowed for GCM), use [`NewGCMWithNonceSize()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#NewGCMWithNonceSize) (note that a nonce other than 12 bytes should only be used for compelling reasons).